# Ionic 3 Component vs Page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Can you tell me what is the difference between `Component` and `Page` generator in the `Ionic 3` app? It seems I can use page life cycle hooks like `ionViewWillLeave` inside the component too.So when should I use angular life cycle hooks then? If it is same then Why it has 2 generators? Hope you'll provide a feedback for this.

*Component generator:*

```
 ionic generate component SubscribeTopicComponent
```

*Page generator:*

```
ionic generate page LoginPage
```

Comment: It may be the same from the Angular point of view, but _Pages_ and _Components_ have a different meaning in Ionic. **Both are just components**, but a Page is a component that will act as an entire view (it may have nested components); we see Ionic pages as a standalone concept. A _component_ will be just part of a bigger component most of the time in Angular apps, so I guess that's the biggest difference with _Pages_.

Comment: About when using Angular's lifecycle hooks, I like to use them when working in components, but I prefer Ionic lifecycle hooks when working on pages. Mostly because `ionViewWillEnter` doesn't make too much sense inside of a simple component, where `ngOnInit` does. I also use some Angular lifecycle hooks on Pages, like the `ngOnDestroy` (I use it to remove all the subscriptions from a page when that page is destroyed). I'm not sure if this is the best way to use them, but I guess it makes sense...

Comment: Yes,What about `ionViewWillLeave()` event for clearing subscriptions?  Is that not good? @sebaferreras

Comment: It wouldn't be right, since that hook means that the user is leaving the page, but not that **the page is going to be destroyed, thus leaving some memory leaks**. Since Ionic caches the pages, if you use `ionViewWillLeave` you may clean up the subscriptions and the next time the user goes to that page (if it was cached, and thus, not created again) the code related to those subscriptions won't be executed.

Comment: I guess that Ionic lifecycle hooks are more related to the user interaction (will enter, will leave, can enter, can leave...) and Angular lifecycle hooks are more related to the different stages of the life of a component (which may not be directly related to the user interaction at all).

Comment: OK.But hope this what we need no? `ionViewWillUnload - Runs when the page is about to be destroyed and have its elements removed.`.Can't we use this? @sebaferreras

Comment: According to your comment above where you created subscriptions? Inside the `constructor`? It depends on the place where we create the subscriptions no? I mean the clearance of subscriptions? If we create it inside the `ionViewDidEnter()` then it doesn't depend on the cache scenario no? @sebaferreras

Comment: I got huge knowledge using your comments above.If you put all together(as an answer) in one place hope others also can get very good insight about this area.@sebaferreras

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Just like you said `ionViewWillUnload ` seems like the right place to do the clean up (for some reason I was not aware of that hook). And also you're right about the cache scenario, if you use Ionic hooks to create the subscription, you can also use Ionic hooks to clean it up. It's all about in what particular time (hook) do you want to do something.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Based on the conversation from the comments:

It may be the same from the Angular point of view, but Pages and Components have a different meaning in Ionic. **In terms of Angular, both are just components**, but **in the context of Ionic, a Page is a component that will act as *an entire view*** (it may have nested components); we see Ionic pages as a **standalone concept**. A component will be just part of a bigger component most of the time in Angular apps, so I guess that's the biggest difference with Pages.

About when using Angular's lifecycle hooks, I like to use them when working in nested components, but I prefer Ionic lifecycle hooks when working on pages. Mostly because things like `ionViewWillEnter` doesn't make too much sense in the context of a simple component, where `ngOnInit` does. That being said, I also used some Angular lifecycle hooks on Pages, like the `ngOnDestroy` (I used it to remove all the subscriptions from a page when that page is going to be destroyed), but just like you said, `ionViewWillUnload` seems to be the right way to do it if we want to use Ionic's lifecycle hooks.

**I guess that *most* of the Ionic lifecycle hooks are more related to the way the user interacts with the page as a whole** (will enter to a page, will leave from a page, can enter to a page, can leave from a page...) **and Angular lifecycle hooks are more related to the different stages of the life of a single component** (the inputs has been initialized, the change detector has checked if there were changes in this component, ...), which as you can see, may not be directly related to the user interaction at all, and usually are things that the user is not aware of.

I'm pretty sure there isn't a rule about which approach is better, but the most important thing is consistency. **I think it make sense to use Ionic lifecycle hooks in the components that are Pages, and use Angular lifecycle hooks inside of nested components**, but you can use a different approach, as long as you do it consistently in the entire app.

Comment: Thanks a lot for nice explanation :)

Comment: Is this answer equally valid for Ionic 4?

Comment: @NigelPeck Not exactly... Please check [this link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/migration/#lifecycle-events) for a good explanation about life cycle hooks in Ionic 4 :)

Answer (score 12):

There are two separate generators because one extra decorator that was added to ionic: @IonicPage

This decorator gives a few advantages over a simple component.

1. Routing - you can signify what is the url of the page, how to get there and what is its default history. With this you can access any page directly without going through the navigation path. The routing to this page can also be done with a string rather than the actual component
2. Lazy loading - the module of a page that has this decorator will be lazy loaded by default when going to the url of the page.
3. No app module reliance - this is more of a personal favorite but when you create modules that are pages you don't have to add them to your original ngModule and this is done automatically on compilation.

For more documentation: 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/

Answer (score 0):

i think that the most important difference in newer version of ionic at least is that when generating pages a module file is included that allow the integration of other component conceptiolly in the page which is not the case for componentd ionic generate a html,css,ts files;